# Maximum likelihood parameter estimation when all I can do is produce samples for fixed parameter values

Tags: sampling, maximum-likelihood

I have a stochastic model (it numerically solves a complicated nonlinear ODE and then computes some statistics of the result) which depends on some parameters.

In addition, I have some data, which I would like to fit my model parameters to. So far so good, this sounds like a job for maximum likelihood. However, I don't have a continuous function that relates the pdf which my model spits out to its parameter values.

In fact, all I can do is sample the pdf at given model parameters (by actually solving the ODE).

Finally, I would like two compare different competing ODE models and decide which one is ``better".

I presume that this must be a relatively common problem, but could not find a standard method to tackle this.

What would be a good approach to estimating my model parameters in this case?

Comment: This sounds like a model calibration problem. I think "Bayesian model calibration of computer models" by Kennedy and O'Hagan is an interesting approach. There are frequentist methods available as well.

Comment: Thank you, @knrumsey. I forgot to mention that I also need to compare two models, which was the reason I was interested in the likelihood in the first place.